How does Lieutenant Kello speaking Italian indicate that he likes Sidney’s people?
One evening, J.J., a columnist, and Sidney, a press agent, encounter Harry Kello, a corrupt
police officer, across the street. They exchange greetings, with J.J. saying “Hello” to Harry,
and Harry responding in Italian, wishing J.J. a good evening and asking how he is doing:

Sidney: Italian, Sidney. That shows Lieutenant Kello likes your
people.
Harry: It's my Brooklyn background, J.J. Good with Yiddish too.

How does Lieutenant Kello speaking Italian indicate that he likes Sidney’s people?

Sidney Falco seems like it might be the name if someone with Italian heritage.
